# Check if path has a specific element in its path

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have been trying to check if a path has '(' in its attribute with the statement below. But it shows an error.

```
<xsl:for-each select="section/section/contains(@num,'(')">
```

When I use the statement above in my XSLT in Altova Spy, it shows a message saying 'invalid XPath expression'. And the browser output is as below:

```
current()/section/section/section/-->contains<--(@num,'a')
```

Please let me know the correct statement to be used. Here `num` is the attribute that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to iterate through the `section`s where `@num` contains `(`?

If so, this should do it:

```
<xsl:for-each select="section/section[contains(@num, '(')]">
```

Comment: this worked thanks. but, one doubt brother. what is the difference between using [] and using ()?

Comment: Square brackets `[]` delineate a [predicate](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathpredicate.php), which is a fundamental concept of XPath.  Parentheses `()` surround function arguments and are used for grouping expressions.